# Jenkins: parallelize test execution

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I started using Jenkins in my project and  I am trying to parallelize my test suite (Rspec test cases) written in 4 files in Jenkins

```
spec/features/
|-- test1.rb
|-- test2.rb
|-- test3.rb
|-- test4.rb
```

We can run all test cases with below command, it will run all tests written in test1.rb ..test4.rb sequentially which will take around 1 hour.

```
script spec/features/
```

If you want to excute test cases from each test file we can run like

```
script spec/features/test1.rb
```

Now I want to parallelize these test cases which can reduce the run from 1hr to 15 mins, All these test cases can run in one machine in parallel

I followed below approach in Jenkins

1) Set a new job "Main_Test_job"

2)

```
Selected "Trigger/Call builds on other projects"
projects to build " Child_test_job"
Build on same node
Predefined Parameters TEST_UNIT=test1.rb
Block until the triggered projects finish their builds ( Not selected this)
```

Add trigger --->

```
Selected "Trigger/Call builds on other projects"
projects to build " Child_test_job"
Build on same node
Predefined Parameters TEST_UNIT=test2.rb
Block until the triggered projects finish their builds ( Not selected this)
```

Add trigger --->

```
Selected "Trigger/Call builds on other projects"
projects to build " Child_test_job"
Build on same node
Predefined Parameters TEST_UNIT=test3.rb
Block until the triggered projects finish their builds ( Not selected this)
```

Add trigger --->

```
Selected "Trigger/Call builds on other projects"
projects to build " Child_test_job"
Build on same node
Predefined Parameters TEST_UNIT=test4.rb
Block until the triggered projects finish their builds ( Not selected this)
```

3)

```
   Created job "Child_test_job" as which was included in main_test_job like below
   Select Build step "Execute Shell" with below command
   script spec/$TEST_UNIT
```

When I start "Main_Test_job", it will automatically start 4 Child_Test_Jobs in same machine, which will reduce my total run time to 15 mins.

- But in this case "Main_test_job" has no way to monitor statuses of 4 
  child_test_jobs, It always succeeds immediately after starting 4
  child jobs
- "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" this option
  monitors child jobs but if we select this option for all child jobs,
  they are running sequentially instead of parallel.

I can't use join plugin as I am not running different jobs instead triggering same job multiple times.

**My Ideas:**

1. have separate jobs for each test.rb and use join trigger to monitor
   statuses of all jobs
2. have some shell script as the post-build task of "Main_Test_job"
       which will aggregate/monitor statuses/results of each jobs.

I think this must be a common scenario in many organizations and there must be a easy way in Jenkins to achieve this.
Please let me know your approaches/ideas. May be I am missing some thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jobs can run in parallel on same machine then Multijob plugin might be of interest to you. It starts the jobs in parallel but waits till all of them finish.

Comment: Thanks NotAgain.., this works for my requirement. I should have researched more on all available plugins, but there are plenty of them :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

You can run any type of jobs by using this plugin.